# Compiling 64-bit GSL on Cygwin using 64-bit GCC

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, gsl

I am trying to compile 64-bit GSL on a Windows 7 machine. Here are the steps I took:

1. Downloaded and untarred the GSL 1.15 source found [here](http://infinity.kmeacollege.ac.in/gnu/gsl/).
2. Tested that I have a 64-bit version of GCC available in the Cygwin shell, by compiling the minimal program

   ```
   // simple.C

   int main() {
       ;
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   using

   ```
   x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -m64 simple.C -o simple
   ```
3. In the untarred folder, I would like to pass the `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` compiler to `./configure` but am not sure how. I took a look at the `configure` file, but that is huge and appears to have been generated using `autoconf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the cygwin prompt you can use:

```
CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc CFLAGS=-m64 ./configure
```

and configure will pick it up.

### Important Note:

I am surprised that you don't have a wrapper `gcc` ... Why don't you try using `./configure` by itself just as is to begin with and see what it does before overriding the C compiler as I showed.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, I did try compiling but that gave me a `checking whether the C compiler (gcc ) works... no` error. Your solution appears to be working, thanks.

Comment: Would you happen to know why if I specify the `CFLAGS=-m64 -arch x86_64"` the compilation fails with a `C compiler can't create executables` error.

Comment: you don't need to specify -arch x86_64; look in config.log and search for the phrase "C compiler can't create executables" and you'll find the exact reason