# make error: Building 64-bit GSL in Cygwin

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, gsl, unix-ar

Continuing from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977104/compiling-64-bit-gsl-on-cygwin-using-64-bit-gcc), I am trying to build 64-bit GSL using GCC in Cygwin.

1. The call to `./configure` (`CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc CFLAGS=-m64 ./configure`) goes through fine, but the call to `make install` results, after a whole load of folders are successfully processed, in

   ./.libs/libgslsiman.a: could not read symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one

   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

   Makefile:326: recipe for target `siman_tsp.exe' failed

   The full call that caused this was

   Making all in siman
   make[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765240/could-not-read-symbols-archive-has-no-index-run-ranlib-to-add-one): Entering directory `/cygdrive/f/programming/c/libraries/gslCompiled/gsl-1.15/siman'

   /bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC    --mode=link x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc  -m64    -o siman_tsp.exe siman_tsp.o libgslsiman.la ../rng/libgslrng.la ../ieee-utils/libgslieeeutils.la ../err/libgslerr.la ../sys/libgslsys.la ../utils/libutils.la -lm

   libtool: link: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -m64 -o .libs/siman_tsp.exe siman_tsp.o  ./.libs/libgslsiman.a ../rng/.libs/libgslrng.a ../ieee-utils/.libs/libgslieeeutils.a ../err/.libs/libgslerr.a ../sys/.libs/libgslsys.a ../utils/.libs/libutils.a
2. Following advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765240/could-not-read-symbols-archive-has-no-index-run-ranlib-to-add-one), I decided to run a `ranlib` in the `./siman/.libs` directory on the `libgslsiman.a` file. Since that didn't work, I also tried to pack it myself using a call to `ar -t libgslsiman.a`.

However, this results in an identical error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You manually forced use of the cross compiler. However, the rest of the build toolchain will still default to the 32-bit Cygwin versions instead of the 64-bit MinGW ones.

Instead of setting `CC=...`, pass `--host x86_64-w64-mingw32` to `./configure` to specify the host environment (ie where the library is going to be used).

Comment: Ok, great. So it is happily compiling in the background. It does ask me to reconsider the choice between `--host` and `--build`. Can you comment on the distinction?

Comment: Oh, why not. I am going to ask another noob question. Once I have done a `make install` I guess that the lib folder is `.libs`, but where is the `include` folder? Should I just make a folder called include which contains all the header files I can find in the GSL folder?

Comment: Ok, remade it with a `--prefix`. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @fgnu: setting `--build` to `i686-pc-cygwin` should make the warning go away; see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139403/whats-the-difference-of-configure-option-build-host-and-target for the difference between `host` and `build`